# How to make a footer be at the bottom anywhere on the page?

Tags: html, css

I know how to create a simple header:

```
<div id="footer">
<h3>My Website</h3>
</div>
```

then in the css:

```
#footer {
bottom: 0px;
}
```

This code makes a footer be at the bottom of the page. What I want to do is make a footer that no matter how far up the page you are, it is displayed. For example, if I scroll right to the top of the page, my footer is shown at the bottom of the screen. No matter where I scroll to, the footer will be pinned to the bottom section of my screen. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Add `position: fixed` to `#footer`? Also your HTML structure seems off..the website contents are inside the footer?

Comment: The best way is to use a grid system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#footer{
bottom: 0px;
position: fixed;
}
```